# Is there any way I can fix this problem with my coral dev board?

Tags: google-coral

I was using coral board with my login credentials before but the SSH didn't seem to work so I removed the keys from the coral in order to generate new ones and now its not letting me in the board. I'm a noob at this, if you answer this please be specific. its for my college project. How do i change the accesskeys in the directory?

```
Waiting for a device...
Connecting to green-horse at 192.168.101.2
Key not present on green-horse -- pushing

Couldn't connect to keymaster on green-horse: [Errno 111] Connection refused.

Did you previously connect from a different machine? If so,
mdt-keymaster will not be running as it only accepts a single key.

You will need to either:
   1) Remove the key from /home/mendel/.ssh/authorized_keys on the
      device via the serial console

- or -

   2) Copy the mdt private key from your home directory on this host
      in ~/.config/mdt/keys/mdt.key to the first machine and use
      'mdt pushkey mdt.key' to add that key to the device's
      authorized_keys file.

Failed to push via keymaster -- will attempt password login as a fallback.
Can't login using default credentials: Bad authentication type; allowed types: ['publickey']
```

Answer (score 0):

ssh should also works (it is what I use), but you'll need generate a key on your host machine and then put it in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the board, there could be multiple keys placed in that file, and mdt needs to be one of them.

1. To recovers mdt access, you can check here: https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/mdt/#recover-mdt-access
2. To ssh into the board, generate your own ssh key:

```
ssh-keygen
```

and your new key will be in `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, you can put that key on the board in order to ssh.

Comment: How can I access my board? I’m new to this. I have Ubuntu installed in my windows computer and that’s where I used to work on the coral from. 
Now when I connected the serial port to the computer it gives me the sound that it’s connected but I don’t see the device or device files anywhere. Where can I find the files I need to delete? I’d appreciate it if you could explain this to me in Layman terms. I don’t know how to switch between directories or how to find them. Where do I need to go exactly? And how? 
Thanks

Comment: Hey, the easiest way is to attach a keyboard and hdmi to the dev board.
Another way is to access the serial (uart) using the `screen /dev/ttyUSB-id` that you used when setting up the board. username and passwords are both mendel.

Comment: Hey,thanks for your quick response. I was following step 1 that you mentioned above and I was able to do step 3 and 4 but I'm not able to reach the board to delete the file.

Comment: Connect to your board using the serial console.
On the board, delete the contents of the /home/mendel/.ssh/authorized_keys file. Not able to do this . please help . I see my board when I type "mdt devices" but how do I access it? I have connected through the serial port, what do I type now?

Comment: I would appreciate if we could connect on LinkedIn, really need some help with this. Thanks looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: not able to do the following - You will need to either:
   1) Remove the key from /home/mendel/.ssh/authorized_keys on the
      device via the serial console

Comment: Hey, if you are in the board's serial console, you should be able to just remove the old authorized_keys or just add your new key to it. It would be a lot more helpful if you can clearly describe why you can't do that rather than just saying that you can't do it. More details would be appreciated

Comment: Take a look at this link: https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/get-started/?gclid=CjwKCAjwzvX7BRAeEiwAsXExoxqsOXBryotmlpSOsipagEhX1lOtDf_CU4orxwKuynWxUFI7cFUVyBoCKX4QAvD_BwE#11-initiate-fastboot-mode
and go to the section that say connect to the serial console.

Comment: I do see the serial connection part in the Documentation. But it doesn't seem to give me any output. When I connect all the cables to the board, it connects the device to my computer but I want to know how I can access the files on the device. You are telling me to use serial port but that isn't working in my case. It makes a sound that the device is connected but how do I access the files (i.e - /home/mendel/.ssh/authorized-keys). How do I delete this? where do I find this directory. I have tried navigating around but I dont see it. Im using UBUNTU app on Windows Laptop. Thanks

Comment: So just to be clear, you've done screen /dev/ttyUSB-device-id and is logged in but can't find the .ssh right? In that case the . In .ssh makes the directory hidden. If you do "ls -a" in /home/mendel it'll show it.

Comment: Also, if you are still having issues with serial interface, the easiest way is to just hook the board directly into a HDMI monitor and do as suggested!